# Select nearest 2 elements either side of a given index in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I need to return a new array with 2 items either side of a given index from within an array.

Consider this array of times:

```
const times = ['17:30', '17:45', '18:00', '18:15', '18:30', '18:45', '19:00', '19:15', '19:30', '19:45', '20:00'];
```

What I need to be able to do is select array item at say, index 5 and return that item, along with 2 either side. This is simple enough, however, if I'm given an index of 1 or 0 or even up to the end of the array length, my code does not work. **I always want to return 5 items**.

Consider the following (very crude) code I have so far:

```
const times = ['17:30', '17:45', '18:00', '18:15', '18:30', '18:45', '19:00', '19:15', '19:30', '19:45', '20:00'],
      givenTime = '19:00';

console.clear();
console.log(getNearestTimes(times, givenTime));

function getNearestTimes(times, givenTime) {

   const nearestTimes = times.filter((element, index, array) => {
     const selected = array.indexOf(givenTime);
     const diffBefore = array.slice(0, selected).length,
         diffAfter = (diffBefore >= 2) ? 2 : (diffBefore + 4);

     if ((index >= (selected - diffAfter) && index < selected) || (index >= selected && index <= (selected + diffAfter)) ) {
       return element;
     }

   });

  return nearestTimes;

}
```

'19:00' will look good, returning:

```
["18:30", "18:45", "19:00", "19:15", "19:30"]
```

'17:30' will look good, returning:

```
["17:30", "17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30"]
```

But, '19:45' will not look good, returning:

```
["19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00"]
```

...ideally, '19:45' would return:

```
["19:00", "19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00"]
```

If there are not enough items after the given time, I'd like to return more before that time, to always make 5 array items return.

I hope this makes sense? It's almost like an array chunk, but only from an array index and not the amount of array's I'd like to return.

Thank you!

Comment: Check if the index is within 2 of either end and add the difference to the other side?

Comment: I have tried this, but because I always want to return 5 items regardless, I need a way to pad it out if there aren't enough items before or after.

Comment: Wait, so if there are only 4 items in the array to begin with, you want to make more? Are you going to make them up (the strings are following a pattern in the example) or return `undefined` or `null` or `""`? And if so, at which side would the new items go?

Comment: Ideally, if there are only 4 items, then just return 4 items. Sorry, I should have clarified on that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could correct the start and end index with some checks.

```js
function getNearestTimes(times, givenTime) {
    var i = times.indexOf(givenTime),
        start = i - 2,
        end = i + 3;

    if (start < 0) {
        start = 0;
        end = 5;
    }
    if (end > times.length) {
        end = times.length;
        start = end - 5;
    }
    return times.slice(start, end);
}

const times = ['17:30', '17:45', '18:00', '18:15', '18:30', '18:45', '19:00', '19:15', '19:30', '19:45', '20:00'];
 
console.log(getNearestTimes(times, '19:00'));
console.log(getNearestTimes(times, '17:45'));
console.log(getNearestTimes(times, '20:00'));
```

Some shorter code of the above with stress on starting.

```js
function getNearestTimes(times, givenTime) {
    var i = times.indexOf(givenTime) - 2;
    i = Math.min(Math.max(0, i), times.length - 5)
    return times.slice(i, i + 5);
}

const times = ['17:30', '17:45', '18:00', '18:15', '18:30', '18:45', '19:00', '19:15', '19:30', '19:45', '20:00'];
 
console.log(getNearestTimes(times, '19:00'));
console.log(getNearestTimes(times, '17:45'));
console.log(getNearestTimes(times, '20:00'));
```

Comment: So simple now that I see it here. Brilliant job! This is exactly what I was looking for thank you. I started going a bit too complicated, which I believe is what started making me confuse myself.

Comment: Basically the same as my answer, only I opted for the ternary operator instead of 'if' statements. Less code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getNearestTimes(times, givenTime) {
        var index = times.indexOf(givenTime);
        index = index < 2 ? 2 : index > times.length -3 ? times.length -3 : index;
        return times.slice(index-2, index+3);
    }
```

If the givenTime doesn't exist in the array - the first 5 items will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this too:

```
function getNearestTimes(times, time, count){         
     var lb = Math.max(times.indexOf(time)-Math.floor(count/2), 0);
     var ub = Math.min(times.indexOf(time)+Math.floor(count/2), times.length - 1);

     var range = (ub - lb) + 1;
     var delta = (count - range);         

     if (delta > 0 && ub === times.length - 1) {
         lb -= delta;
     }
     else if (delta > 0 && lb === 0) {
         ub += delta;
     }

     return times.slice(lb, ub + 1);
}


getNearestTimes(times, '17:30', 5);
getNearestTimes(times, '18:30', 5);
```